# Extjs4 combobox displayValue in grid

Tags: combobox, extjs4

Please, help.
I want to show my `displayValue` in the Grid.
I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133453/combobox-in-editable-grid-cant-see-the-value), but I can't understand how use it. My code:

```
columns:[...,{
    header: 'Product',
    id: 'combo',
    locked: true,
    dataIndex: 'prod_id',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        store: new Ext.data.Store({
            fields: ['value','display'],
            data: prod_list
    }),
    displayField: 'display',
    valueField: 'value'
    }
},...]
```

### Solution

```
Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer = function(combo){
    return function(value){
    var record = combo.findRecord(combo.valueField || combo.displayField, value);
        return record ? record.get(combo.displayField) : combo.valueNotFoundText;
    }
}

{
    header: 'Товар',
    id: 'combo',
    locked: true,
    dataIndex: 'prod_id',
    editor: MyEditor,
    renderer: Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(MyEditor)
}
```

I tried to define editor outside of the column array.

```
    var MyEditor = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
        store: new Ext.data.Store({
            fields: ['value','display'],
            data: prod_list
        }),
        displayField: 'display',
        valueField: 'value'
    });
```

#### And all is fine, **but I can't edit it**. What is the problem?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: You should probably post your solution as an answer and then accept it, so that this question is not considered 'unanswered' by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    fields: ['value','display'],
    data: prod_list
});
```

...

```
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: myStore,
                displayField: 'display',
                valueField: 'value'
            },
            renderer: function(val){
                index = myStore.findExact('value',val); 
                if (index != -1){
                    rs = myStore.getAt(index).data; 
                    return rs.display; 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a **celleditor** plugin.

It is best if  you define the renderer as a  reusable object so that you can globally control the behavior of your combo columns.

Since you are using ExtJS4, I added an alternative way to show the displayField of the combo editor in a cell, without having to define the editor outside of the scope of a column.

**First define the renderer:**

```
Ext.ns("Ext.ux.util");

Ext.ux.util.ComboRenderer = function(val, metaData){
    var combo = metaData.column.getEditor();
    if(val && combo && combo.store && combo.displayField){
        var index = combo.store.findExact(combo.valueField, val);
        if(index >= 0){
            return combo.store.getAt(index).get(combo.displayField);
        }
    }
    return val;
};
```

**Then give your grid a cellediting plugin:**

```
  plugins: [
    {
      ptype: 'cellediting',
      clicksToEdit: 1
    }
  ]
```

**And finally, assign the ComboRenderer to your column's renderer property like this:**

```
{
  header: 'Product',
  dataIndex: 'prod_id',
  renderer: Ext.ux.util.ComboRenderer,
  editor: {
    xtype: 'combo',
    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        fields: ['value','display'],
        data: prod_list
    })
  }
}
```